# JSON double quote mystery

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Leaning JSON, I'd like to think that followed the syntax tips to the tee. I wanted to start loading datasets into JSON and manipulating them using Python. Writing the dataset I started entering the data but I kept getting this error.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 2 (char 129)
```

Although I followed multiple tutorials, I can't get to understand where my error is coming from?

```
        [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "email": "x@x",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes",
            },
            {
                "name": "y",
                "email": "y@y",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes",
            },
            {
                "name": "z",
                "email": "info@z.com",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes",
            },
        ]
```

Comment: JSON can't handle those trailing commas like Python can. E.g. the comma after `"contacted": "Yes",` is a problem.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Json you show in your question is not valid because of the last comma you have in every object.

Here's a valid version:

```
[
    {
        "name": "x",
        "email": "x@x",
        "location": "Yorkville Village",
        "contacted": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "name": "y",
        "email": "y@y",
        "location": "Yorkville Village",
        "contacted": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "name": "z",
        "email": "info@z.com",
        "location": "Yorkville Village",
        "contacted": "Yes"
    }
]
```

Always check if your JSON is valid using a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Even that last ` },` had an extra comma. Thank you so much! that website is definitely getting a bookmark!

Comment: Ahahaha sorry I missed that too :)

This one is even better, it allows you to edit a JSON using the GUI: http://jsoneditoronline.org/  also available as Chrome Extension, super handy.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Have fun and happy hacking :)

Answer (score 3):

It's expecting "property name enclosed in double quotes", as in "expecting [another] property [with a] name [that is] enclosed in double quotes"; it's expecting another property. This is because you have extra commas at the ends of your `k:v` pairs.

You want:

```
        [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "email": "x@x",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "name": "y",
                "email": "y@y",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "name": "z",
                "email": "info@z.com",
                "location": "Yorkville Village",
                "contacted": "Yes"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Now I get `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`

Comment: Even on that I had an extra comma. Thank you so much Matthew!

Comment: Thank goodness, I was confused for a second. You're welcome. :)